# Deleting files uploaded to GA with google apps script by upload id

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to create a Google Apps Script that would delete old files uploaded to GA, and then upload the current one.

The line for uploading and the line for listing the uploads work well:

```
var upload = Analytics.Management.Uploads.uploadData(accountId, webPropertyId, customDataSourceId, blobData);
var request = Analytics.Management.Uploads.list(accountId, webPropertyId, customDataSourceId)
```

However, I cannot make the upload deletion to work. I try the following code:

```
for (var k = 0; k <= request["items"].length - 1; k++) {
    var customDataImportUid = request["items"][k]["id"]; //get the unique upload id
    //delete the file with a specific upload id:
   var deleteUpload = Analytics.Management.Uploads.deleteUploadData(
        accountId, webPropertyId, customDataSourceId, customDataImportUid);
}
```

I get the error:

> GoogleJsonResponseException: Invalid value 'UA-xxxxxxxx-x'. Values must match the following regular expression: '\d+'.

It seems that the script is trying to use the property ID as the account ID, so I try a different approach:

```
for (var k = 0; k <= request["items"].length - 1; k++) {
   var customDataImportUid = request["items"][k]["id"]; //get the unique upload id
   //delete the file with a specific upload id:
   var deleteUpload = Analytics.Management.Uploads.deleteUploadData(
       0, accountId, webPropertyId, customDataSourceId, customDataImportUid);
}
```

But then get the error:

> Exception: Extra args block must be a javascript object literal.

Two questions:

1. Why, if I pass accountId as the first parameter, do I get the error?
2. How can I get the right parameter for Data Import IDs? How would I transform the ID to a javascript object literal?

Comment: Well, does your `accountId` variable satisfy the `\d+` regex? Or does it have `UA-` at the start? Documentation says it should be a `long` i.e. numeric only. You can compare the value to what it should be with your `request` variable, i.e. `Logger.log("Real value:" + request["items"][k]["accountId"] + " my value:" + accountId);`  **I also wonder why you add the 0 in the second attempt**

Comment: It does - see the top two lines, where I have no problem in applying the same accountId. The logger also shows the correct result. What I can't understand (maybe the documentation is not 100% accurate) that I can't use accountId as the first parameter for deleting the files - it has to be in the second place. That's why I put '0' as the first parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your request is failing is because your request is incorrect:

If I use the Script Editor to begin writing my own function, I get the following method signature:
[image]

The first argument to that function should thus not be `0` or `accountId` at all. It needs to be the request resource.
From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/uploads/deleteUploadData#request-body), it should be something like this:

```
{  
  'customDataImportUids': ['AAABBBCCCDDD111222',
                           'xLh4wXtzQT6uxe-_OWelog']
}
```

Your usage was placing this parameter as the last argument, rather than the first argument

Note that the method does not return anything, so your variable `deleteUpload` will be undefined. Rewritten, this becomes:

```
myCustomDataImportUids = [];
for(var k = 0; k < request.items.length; ++k) {
  myCustomDataImportUids.push(request.items[k].id);
}
// Delete them.
Analytics.Management.Uploads.deleteUploadData(
  {customDataImportUids: myCustomDataImportUids},
  accountId, webPropertyId, customDataSourceId
);
```